# How do I transition a centre aligned dynamic text?

Tags: jquery, html, css, reactjs

I have a centre aligned text that changes due to some action. Can I put a transition there? ([codepen](http://codepen.io/prvashisht/pen/vywqYQ))

HTML :

```
<div id="container">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit</div>
```

CSS :

```
#container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #000;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

(The above codepen is a sample of dynamic data, in actual, my data is being changed by react states)

EDIT: Only the last part of the text changes for ex `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit` changes to `Lorem ipsum dolor ...`. So the I want to show the reduced text coming to center from left (as the remaining text will be on left side when it's cut off)

Comment: Yes, you can transition the text. What kind of transition are you trying to achieve? Can you add this information to your question, please? Thank you.

Comment: You could cross-fade a couple of divs that are on different z-index planes. You will want to think about debouncing.

Comment: which transition you want to add?

Comment: transition is effect and you can try many different things with it. please check below two URLS and you will understand most things.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions

-----------------------------

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transition/

Comment: Thanks for asking more information. I've updated the question.

Comment: See. if you try to transit the text directly it wont work. Infact You have to transform scale E.g. 0.9 to previous text 'that should be in span'. than after this animation complete. you can show your new dynamic text..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

```js
$("#container div").hover(function() {
  this.innerHTML = "This is some sample dynamic text This is some sample dynamic text This is some sample dynamic text This is some sample dynamic text This is some sample dynamic text This is some sample dynamic text This is some sample dynamic text This is some sample dynamic text This is some sample dynamic text This is some sample dynamic text This is some sample dynamic text";
}, function() {
  this.innerHTML = "This is some sample dynamic text that does nothing This is some sample dynamic text that does nothing This is some sample dynamic text that does nothing";
});
```

```css
#container {
  height: 20px;
  background: #000;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
#container div {
  width: 400px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  max-width: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: all ease-in-out .9s;
}
#container div:hover {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  white-space: normal;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div>This is some sample dynamic text that does nothing This is some sample dynamic text that does nothing This is some sample dynamic text that does nothing</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#container:after{
   content:'this is dynamic';
}
```

or, in JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = "Paragraph changed!"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple transition using only `CSS`, Similarly you can have plenty of effects as you wish..... without having to use JS.

```css
#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  background: #000;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
}
#container:hover > .static {
  top: -20px;
}
#container:hover > .dynamic {
  top: 0px;
}
#container .static {
  top: 0px;
}
#container .dynamic {
  top: 20px;
}
#container > div {
  position: absolute;
  left: auto;
  right: auto;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="static">This is some sample dynamic text that does nothing</div>
  <div class="dynamic">This is some sample dynamic text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I updated the question. Basically, just the text at the end is changed by an ellipsis. And I've mentioned that the text is not changed by a simple hover. I have a react app in which the text change is done by some state change.